# Is there an any other alternative for the given code?

Tags: plotting

This code does not work in the version I have

```
NumberLinePlot[{((16 (1 + x^2)^2 Sin[3 x ] - 2 x)) < 
   0, (16 (1 + x^2)^2 Sin[3 x ] - 2 x) > 0}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: Works fine in v12.0 and later on my Mac

Comment: Works fine in 11.3 on my Mac.

Comment: Try `Clear["Global\`*"]; neg = Reduce[{((16 (1 + x^2)^2 Sin[3 x] - 2 x)) < 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x]; pos = Reduce[{((16 (1 + x^2)^2 Sin[3 x] - 2 x)) > 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x]; NumberLinePlot[{neg, pos}, {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: What version do you have and what goes wrong?

Comment: @m_goldberg Version 10.4 and the error is ""NumberLinePlot::invlvar: Valid variable specification expected beyond position 1 in -2 x+16 (1+x^2)^2 Sin[3 x]<0. >>""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
Plot[0, {x, 0, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[x, 16 (1 + x^2)^2 Sin[3 x] - 2 x], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Brown, Blue}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Green], 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```